# How do you find which primary link is 'active' (current page is a part of)

Tags: php, drupal

Bear with me as I am still completely new with drupal and I don't know the key terms but what I'm trying to do should be straight forward.

Say I have a page that is part of another page in the menu system. The child pages can be seen as secondary links.
From the theme's page.tpl.php, how would I go about finding what primary link the current page is a part of?

For example, lets say my sites structure is

```
Home
about us
pages
  page1
  page2
```

If I were on page1 or 2, How would I figure out that we are under pages?

Comment: Is this for Drupal 6 or Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0):

Check out: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/group/menu/6

But the function you probably want to deal with is: `menu_get_active_trail()`

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_active_trail/6

Comment: I tried using that function, and the only information it gave me was information regarding the current page (eg, if i'm on page 1, it just shows info about page 1) and nothing about the parent

Comment: Did you try iterating through it?

Comment: i printed out the contents using print_r().
  
EDIT: I realized that the child pages are actually "primary links" as well, however they are a child of pages, so it is treated as a secondary link. can this be whats causing the problem?